# Create frequency table of unique values from list of lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of lists like the following:

test = [['abc', 'bcd', 'dce'], ['abc', 'ab', 'cd'], ['cd', be']]

I want to get the frequency of each unique value for each sublist. For example, the first sublist has

abc    1
bcd    1
dce    1
ab     0
ab     0
cd     0
be     0

I am trying something like the following:

```
def freq(list_):
    df = []
    for c in list_:
        df_= pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Counter(c), orient = "index")
        df_.index.name = 'motif'
        df_.reset_index(inplace = True)
        df.append(df_)
        print(df_)
    print(df)
    df = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=[0],
                                    how='outer'), df).fillna('void')
    df = df.T
    df.columns = df.iloc[0]
    df = df.iloc[1:]
    df[df == "void"] = 0
    col_names = sorted(df.columns)
    df = df[col_names]
    vals = df.values
    sums = np.sum(vals, axis = 1)
    freqs = vals / sums[:,None]
    return pd.DataFrame(freqs).T
```

But it is not working.

My desired output is a data frame with each unique value as a column feature, and each sublist as a row.

How can this be done?

EDIT:

Desired output:

```
   ab  abc  bcd  be  cd  dce
0   0    .33    .33   0   0    .33
1   .33    .33    0   0   .33    0
2   0    0    0   .5   .5    0
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) with `sum`:

```
df = pd.get_dummies(pd.DataFrame(test), prefix_sep='', prefix='').sum(level=0, axis=1)
print (df)
   abc  cd  ab  bcd  be  dce
0    1   0   0    1   0    1
1    1   1   1    0   0    0
2    0   1   0    0   1    0
```

Or `Counter` with `DataFrame` constructor, replace `NaN`s to `0` and convert to `integer`s:

```
from collections import Counter

df = pd.DataFrame([Counter(x) for x in test]).fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
   ab  abc  bcd  be  cd  dce
0   0    1    1   0   0    1
1   1    1    0   0   1    0
2   0    0    0   1   1    0
```

And then:

```
df = df.div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
print (df)
         ab       abc       bcd   be        cd       dce
0  0.000000  0.333333  0.333333  0.0  0.000000  0.333333
1  0.333333  0.333333  0.000000  0.0  0.333333  0.000000
2  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.5  0.500000  0.000000
```

Comment: I guess this wasn't in the question itself, but in my attempted solution I changed it from count values to frequency in each row. What would be the easiest way to make this change?

Comment: I could see a use for an efficient version in the near future, so that would be appreciated!

Comment: hmm, then `Counter` solution should be better for performance.

Comment: @JackArnestad - Is possible check performance with real data? I just realize generate dummy data is not easy.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tag `pandas`, there is one solution from `pandas` `get_dummies`

```
pd.DataFrame(test).stack().str.get_dummies().sum(level=0)
Out[301]: 
   ab  abc  bcd  be  cd  dce
0   0    1    1   0   0    1
1   1    1    0   0   1    0
2   0    0    0   1   1    0
```

Updated

```
s=pd.DataFrame(test).stack().str.get_dummies().sum(level=0)

s.div(s.sum(1),0)
Out[312]: 
         ab       abc       bcd   be        cd       dce
0  0.000000  0.333333  0.333333  0.0  0.000000  0.333333
1  0.333333  0.333333  0.000000  0.0  0.333333  0.000000
2  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.5  0.500000  0.000000
```

Comment: I guess this wasn't in the question itself, but in my attempted solution I changed it from count values to frequency in each row. What would be the easiest way to make this change?

Comment: Just added. Thanks for your help!